# Can we say "He is a scum"?

Tags: word-usage, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, countability

According to dictionaries, "scum" can be used in countable or uncountable sense; but "He is a scum" sounds wrong to my ears. Can the sentences "He is a scum" and "He is scum" be used interchangeably?

Comment: Lexico says that [**scum**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/scum) is a *mass noun*. I have never seen it used in the plural, and with an article in sentences such as "He is the scum of the earth" or "I scrubbed the scum off the basin."

Comment: @Weather Vane Thanks. Which one do you think is correct between “He is scum” and “ He is a scum”?

Comment: Why did I get so many dislikes? Should the question be more detailed?

Comment: You are right in saying that 'He is a scum' is wrong. It is not used as a countable noun in that sense, only in the sense of 'the scum on a pond' and the like.

Comment: Downvoters are so terrible when they are clueless. This is actually an excellent question.

Comment: @Lambie I agree. This is a valid question. That is why I voted to let it stay open with a few tweaks.

Comment: @Lambie I only see my upvote on your answer. There is no other votes as yet, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

The word scum to refer to a person comes from the word scum used to describe (usually unpleasant) organic matter that floats to the surface of liquids. It is not always nasty, i.e. **tea scum**. It's shiny but not unpleasant.

For example:

> May 2, 2013 By RMBEL
>   **Algae and lake scums** Lakes contain various algae and scums throughout the year, so how do you know which are natural and which
>   can cause harm to humans or to the lake? Today, I’ll describe some of
>   the most common substances that lake users will come across.

And here:

**Algal Blooms, Scums and Mats in Ponds**

[Article on freshwater algae](https://lmcd.org/wp-cms/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Freshwater-Algae.pdf)

[algae and lake scums](https://www.rmbel.info/algae-and-lake-scums/)

Generally, one would see **types of scum**, but **scums** is perfectly acceptable here as well in a technical context.

However, to insult a person, it's a mass noun and if you insult many people (a plurality), you would say: "They are scum." And not scums. Similarly, one sees: "They are trash." (AmE) or "Those are rubbish." (BrE) used as a mass noun....

That said, if you're looking for a countable noun, there is always **scumbag**, which can take an s: **scumbags**.